# Why my mapping has unsupported parameters?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping that is giving errors with the latest elasticsearch:

```
PUT mydoctype/_mapping
{
  "mydoctype": {
    "properties": {
          "location" : {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error... what is wrong?
"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mydoctype : {properties={location={type=geo_point}}}]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mapping type which is no longer supported. See [Removal of Mapping Type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). Make a following request insteed:

```
PUT myindex/_mappings
{
    "properties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point" 
        }
    }
}
```